# Symfony liipimaginebundle: set request context scheme to https

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, liipimaginebundle

I have done following things:

```
img_path = 'abc.jpg'
<img src="{{ img_path | imagine_filter(filter) }}">
```

So I want to have url with `https`. Currently I am getting url with `http`.

I have set `router.request_context.scheme: https` in parameters. But didn't work.

So actually I want to set `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/RequestContext.php`
`scheme` property to `https`.

Answer (score 1):

I changed  liip/imagine-bundle/Imagine/Cache/Resolver/WebPathResolver.php because I had the same problem.

In line 151 I put **$this->requestContext->setScheme('https');** :

```
    $baseUrl = rtrim($baseUrl, '/\\');
    $this->requestContext->setScheme('https');
    return sprintf('%s://%s%s%s',
        $this->requestContext->getScheme(),
        $this->requestContext->getHost(),
        $port,
        $baseUrl
    );
```

But in my case, the old developer of the project completely changed this framwork and I will never be able to update it

Comment: Watch out when you modify core classes, you won't be able to update your framework anymore. Rather extend the class and overwrite the affected method.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the old developer of the project changed this framework completely.

Comment: is there any new solution?

Answer (score -1):

Sets the HTTP host to use for future requests. You must call this before issuing any HTTP requests.
host is the name of the host, optionally with port (e.g. 'google.com' or 'localhost:5984') scheme the protocol scheme to use. Valid values are 'http', 'https'

Comment: Where to set HTTP host? I have tried to set this parameter ```router.request_context.scheme: https``` in parameter.yml file. But it didn't work.